# Interpretation of confidence intervals for population data?

Tags: confidence-interval, population, census

Suppose that I have access to the observations from the entire population $x_1,...,x_N$. If I fit a distribution to this population $x_i\sim F(\cdot ; \theta)$, and I calculate confidence intervals/regions for $\theta$,

- what is the interpretation of these intervals/regions?
- Haven't I already obtained the true value of the parameter as there are no more individuals?

Answer (score 3):

> what is the interpretation of these intervals/regions?

Even if you can compute the confidence interval in usual manner, those interval are senseless. The usual story behind the confidence interval rules suppose that you collect a sample by $iid$ sampling on infinite large population. For finite population some ad hoc adjustments exist (read here: [http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/utm218s07/FinitePop.pdf](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/%7Ebrunner/oldclass/utm218s07/FinitePop.pdf)). From those adjustments you can understand/remember that "confidence interval" regard the *inference from sample to population*. If you have data at population level the estimators are no more random variables; then no standard deviation exist and, therefore, no confidence intervals.

> Haven't I already obtained the true value of the parameter as there
> are no more individuals?

If your distribution, or model more in general, are correctly specified the reply is yes.
Otherwise your estimates are *biased*. Note that biasedness can remain at population level also. This discussion is strongly related: [Do we need hypothesis testing when we have all the population?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478142/do-we-need-hypothesis-testing-when-we-have-all-the-population/484906#484906)  I added there some consideration about *prediction* al *causal inference*.