# Theoretical Results Regarding the Sum of OLS Coefficients

Tags: least-squares, prediction, multicollinearity

Consider the following regression model
$$
y=\beta _{1}x_{1}+\beta _{2}x_{2}+u
$$
where $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are two random variables and $u$ is a disturbance
term. I simulate the model drawing $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ and $u$ from a standard
normal distribution (mean 0 and standard deviation of 1) and making the two regressors
$x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ correlated with correlation coefficient of $0.995$.
I set $\beta _{1}=\beta _{2}=0.5$.

The high correlation gives obvious problems visible in the large swings of
the estimated coefficients in the table below. What strikes me, however, is
that their sum ($\hat{\beta}_{1}+\hat{\beta}_{2}$) seems rather stable and
centers around the true sum of 1. The table below shows the coefficients and their sum for five different draws.

|  | (1) | (2) | (3) | (4) | (5) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| beta1 | -0.445 | 0.$_{.}$467 | 0.966 | 0.538 | 0.189 |
| beta2 | 1.451 | 0.505 | -0.0443 | 0.479 | 0.862 |
| beta1+beta2 | 1.006 | 0.972 | 1.013 | 1.012 | 1.051 |

When one coefficient goes up, the other seems to go down.

**Question**: Is this something well known? Does this have a name?

This could as well be trivial, but it seems that this may somehow be related to the fact
that while OLS gives inconsistent estimates when the regressors are highly correlated, it still allows us to predict $y$
fairly well. I am referring to what Diebold calls p-consistency. See for
example

- [T-consistency vs. P-consistency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265739)
- [Why don't linear regression assumptions matter in machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486672)

The full table with the estimation results of the five regressions is

|     |  y               |  y             |      y        |    y          | y   |
|-----|------------------|----------------|------------------|---------------|--|
|x1_1 |-0.445   (0.310)  |                |                  |               |                |
|x2_1 |1.451*** (0.308)  |                |                  |               |                |
|x1_2 |                  | 0.467 (0.313)  |                  |               |                |
|x2_2 |                  | 0.505 (0.313)  |                  |               |                |
|x1_3 |                  |                 |  0.966** (0.326) |              |                |
|x2_3 |                  |                 |  0.0443  (0.328) |              |                |
|x1_4 |                  |                 |                  | 0.538 (0.320)|                |
|x2_4 |                  |                 |                  | 0.479 (0.319)|                |
|x1_5 |                  |                 |                  |              | 0.189 (0.312)  |
|x2_5 |                  |                 |                  |              | 0.862** (0.312)|
|N    | 1000             |  1000          | 1000             |  1000         | 1000           |
|R-sq | 0.5114           |  0.4926        | 0.4861           | 0.5155        | 0.5467         |
Standard errors in parentheses

- p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001

Comment: It's called *multicollinearity.*  But I see you have already used that tag, suggesting you are trying to ask something else.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, but does multicollinearity mean that the sum of the two coefficients must somehow add up to the true sum? This seems reasonable, I believe, but I wasn't sure about it. Also, if this would not be the case, we couldn't predict y so well despite the inconsistently estimated coefficients.

Comment: I have difficulties formatting the second table. In the preview, the table looks fine but when I post it, it gets messed up. Sorry for that.

Comment: "Multicollinearity" means almost collinear.  Collinearity, in turn, implies at least one linear combination of the variables is constant.  The dual version of that is at least one linear combination of the parameter estimates is constant.

Comment: I see. Yes, that's the answer. Thanks.