# Are we estimating a conditional mean in OLS when the error term is not Gaussian?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, linear-model, error, conditional-expectation

A standard, even if not strictly mandatory, assumption in OLS regression is that the error term is Gaussian.

$$y = X\beta + \epsilon$$

$$\epsilon \sim N(0, \Sigma)
$$

We also talk about the regression as predicting the mean of some distribution.

What restrictions are there on the error term for us to be estimating a conditional mean?

Comment: One simple answer is this: When you apply least squares to simple one-way ANOVA data (regardless of any assumptions), the ordinary sample averages for each group are obtained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applied on a data sample, a linear regression estimated by OLS minimizes the sum of squared errors. In population, the sum of squared errors is minimized by the conditional expectation. Under assumptions that guarantee [predictive consistency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265739/t-consistency-vs-p-consistency) of the OLS estimator, OLS regression will be estimating the conditional mean. The assumptions can be found in [this answer by Michael](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265739/t-consistency-vs-p-consistency/471922#471922).